# Is there a way to redirect to the same route in drawer navigation with different parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I created multiple drawer menus items in that few will redirect to the same component but render with different parameter 
Is there any way to do this .?

Answer (score 0):

Your url could look like this: 'url/.../[menu-item-name]'.
Then on each menu item onClick method you could push state with new url using react-router-redux. f.e.

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
...
onClick() {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  dispatch(push('url/menu-item-1', {
     prop1: 1,
     prop2: 2,
  }));
}
```

and to access those props:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/url/:menuIitem"
    render={ ({ match: { params }, location: { state: props } }) => (
        <Component
            menuItemName={ prams.menuItem }
            {...props}
        />
    ) }
/>
```

Comment: I am not using redux